# trying to export module but I can't

Tags: node.js

I want to get the `instance`  from the callback function but if i use it I can't export keepAlive function so is there is any way to get the `instance`  without the callback function
I can't  use `require("")` cuz it's in a package

this is my code

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();

module.exports = {
    callback: ({ message, args, text, client, prefix, instance , keepAlive }) => {


        function keepAlive() {
            server.listen(3000, () => { console.log("Server is Ready!!") });
        }

        module.exports = keepAlive;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to acheive with this code. Try to add a code showing how you intend to use it. You can define the keepAlive function outside the callback function like this `module.exports.keepAlive = function() { server.lis... }`

Comment: There is no discord.js specific code in here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const express = require('express');
const server = express();

const Options = {
    callback: ({ message, args, text, client, prefix, instance , keepAlive }) => {


        function keepAlive() {
            server.listen(3000, () => { console.log("Server is Ready!!") });
        }

        
    }
}

module.exports = Options;
```